# unable to download csv from django admin on HEROKU

Tags: python, django, csv, heroku

This is my code for downloading csv, pretty straight forward,

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):


 actions = ['download_csv_file','send_mail']

 def download_csv_file(self, request, queryset):
    import StringIO
    f = StringIO.StringIO()
    import csv
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['first name','mobile','email','gender'])
    for i in queryset:
        print(i)
        writer.writerow([i.first_name,i.mobile,i.email,i.gender])
    f.seek(0)

    from django.http import HttpResponse
    response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=User-info.csv'
    return response
```

This works perfectly on my localhost.

But I am unable to download csv when I deployed it on heroku.

It gives a `500 interval server error`.

This is the corresponding log record,

```
2017-12-03T14:36:06.940950+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/admin/bookings/user/" host=xxxxx-xx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxx fwd="xx.xx.xx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=47ms status=500 bytes=234 protocol=https
```

I couldnt get Why is it happening on heroku.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't use print in production. Not sure if that is the problem but you should definitely remove that line.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, but I am still getting the same error. How can I print the stack trace in heroku?

Comment: Don’t know heroku to answer but your problem is likely on the server ( Apache? ) in front of the Django instance.